# How to write a shortcut JSX function for element className?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting out learning react. I want to write a function so I can use JSX like `<element {classes("btn btn-large red-text etc")}>`.

So far I have done `yarn add classnames` and here are the two files I'm trying to accomplish the task. Please help me, and forgive me if this is a really bad way to do things in React. It's just where my interest took me. Thank you.

**/app/src/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import classes from 'components/classnames';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <p {classes("class-a class-b class-c")>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**/app/src/components/classnames.js**

```
class ClassNames extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      `className="${classnames(props)}"`
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: For learning purposes: sure, you can do this. For real code: just use the `classnames` library in the normal way. There's not much reason to go against the flow here. I found this related issue: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames/issues/132

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this with the "spread" operator, which expands an object into props;

**/app/src/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import classes from './classes';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <p {...classes("class-a class-b class-c")}>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**/app/src/classes.js**

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

export default function(...args) {
  return { className: classNames(...args) };
}
```